# A high school movie that students protest of their school conditions

Tags: identify-this-movie

I'm looking for a movie that the angry students protest of their insufficient school conditions in a poor neighborhood. It was an USA made movie and probably from late 90's.

A substitute or new teacher goes to the principal office, takes care of the procedures and then goes down to meet his students. He was black, kinda tall, in his 40's, short black haired or bald. He was probably English or literature teacher, something about language. When he meets the class, he finds out that due to the lack of classrooms they can't have a lesson in the school at that day. He get confused about this situation and took his class to a cafe nearby.

The students were getting annoyed about this status and they were constantly interrupting their teacher. He tried to convince them to continue the lesson but everytime he came up with lots of objections. They told the teacher to even if they graduate, due to the high crime and violence in the neighborhood they'd face with lots of difficulties, violence and poor jobs with a few salary. Most of the students were black, with couple of white and Hispanic amongst them and aged between 16-18, about 15-20 in total. They all had a poor family and were living in a poor condition.

When they went back to the school they started to arguing with the principal and some other people because of they've had a class at a cafe. During the argument one of the students freak out, took of his gun and started to shooting. People screamed and tried to escape. I guess the principal or a some other guy got shoot. The teacher tried to calm down the student with the gun. Their classmates backed him up and they decided to lock themselves in the school with a person  he shoot to take an attention and tell their problems to the authorities.

In a short time there were only few people left in the school. The students,the teacher and the injured person. They barricaded the front door, windows and the exits. The police surrounded the area and told them to get out and stop this protest immediately by megaphone. Meanwhile the teacher tried to convince the students to stop that madness and told them to they wouldn't have come up with a solution by this way. A little after this conversation a SWAT team cleared the barricades and tried to reach them. Also a police helicopter was flying over the building and there were some TV reporters outside.

They blocked the stairs and went to the top floor. They locked themselves in the library i think. Two girls were stressed about this situation and expressed their concerns. One one them was white, fat and had piercings. She told her friend to she had a relationship with a boy recently and she could have been pregnant. She told her also that, all she wanted a kiss from that boy but he never kissed her. The other girl was black and had long, curly black hair.

After this conversation there was a commercial break and I couldn't watch the rest.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sounds bit similar to [Light It Up](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0172726/)

> A group of teens is bent on improving the run-down conditions of their high-school.

Movie trailer :

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_It_Up_(film)) has full plot synopsis, some matching points are:

- Knowles takes students to  dine because no place left in school
- pregnant classmate
- most of the cast is black
- Officer got shot and held captive

etc etc. There are slight variation from your version but overall structure appears same to me.

Comment: @michael Thank you for giving us pretty detailed identification question.